# Adding styles to a table in strapi Markdown text field

Tags: reactjs, markdown, strapi

Currently I have a Rich text field in strapi that uses markdown for the content. I wanted to add a table in this so I wrote the following code:

```
<table style="border:2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong>Country</strong>
      </td>
      <td>
        <strong>Visa free</strong>
      </td>
      <td>
        <strong>Visa on arrival</strong>
      </td>
      <td>
        <strong>eVisa</strong>
      </td>
      <td>
        <strong>Duration of stay and notes</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

This gives the following output on the webpage:

[image]

I want there to atleast be a solid border for this table.

The following is my React code to show the rich content from strapi:

```
<ReactMarkdown children={posts.Content} remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]} />
```

Ive also tried doing the following:

```
| Col1Row1    | Col2Row1  |
| Col1Row2    | Col2Row2  |
| Col1Row3    | Col2Row3  |
| Col1Row4    | Col2Row4  |
| Col1Row5    | Col2Row5  |
| Col1Row6    | Col2Row6  |
| Col1Row7    | Col2Row7  |
```

But this gives me this output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the rich text editor in `strapi` is a `markdown` editor, so it does **NOT** understand & interpret HTML correctly. In order to generate a table using markdown you will have to follow the [markdown cheat sheet](https://www.markdownguide.org/cheat-sheet/).

Additionally, in the front end you will have to use a [markdown parser](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown) to interpret and display the markdown correctly.

##### Sample table markdown syntax

```
| Col1Row1    | Col2Row1  |
|-------------|-----------|
| Col1Row2    | Col2Row2  |
| Col1Row3    | Col2Row3  |
| Col1Row4    | Col2Row4  |
| Col1Row5    | Col2Row5  |
| Col1Row6    | Col2Row6  |
| Col1Row7    | Col2Row7  |
```

##### Markdown Output

| Col1Row1 | Col2Row1 |
| --- | --- |
| Col1Row2 | Col2Row2 |
| Col1Row3 | Col2Row3 |
| Col1Row4 | Col2Row4 |
| Col1Row5 | Col2Row5 |
| Col1Row6 | Col2Row6 |
| Col1Row7 | Col2Row7 |

##### Sample Markdown Parser implementation in React

```react
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'

const markdown = `Just a link: https://reactjs.com.`

ReactDom.render(
  <ReactMarkdown children={markdown} remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]} />,
  document.body
)
```

###### NOTE:

***Make sure you don't have any CSS styling that hides the display of borders on the table, or else you would be wasting quite a bit of time debugging the markdown.***

**P.S**: You could use [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) great tool for easily generating the markdown for your complicated tables and also view the changes in real time.

Comment: I'm already using <ReactMarkdown children={posts.Content} rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]} /> , so how do I add a markdown parser.

Comment: Actually, markdown parser is just something that understands markdown syntax and convert's it to it's equivalent `HTML` syntax. So I believe your front end code is correct. Did you use the same library that I linked in the answer? if yes, then you only need to format your markdown syntax of the table and you should get the correct output in the front end.

Comment: Yes, I am using react-markdown library but for some reason the code is still not showing up correctly. I have updated the question to show the output of how it looks like right now

Comment: I have updated my answer as well to show you a sample implementation in React. There are more examples in the library Github page.

Comment: Yes so I have tried the following and it gives me the correct output but the table still does not have any borders which puts me back to square 1

Comment: I checked the syntax you attached in the question. It's still not correct. Please copy the table markdown syntax from my answer and use the [remark-gfm](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark-gfm) plugin instead of the rehype plugin. Also, can you please share the image of what you mean by "it gives me the correct output but the table still does not have any borders"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236777/discussion-between-jay-modi-and-salvino).